# VBA Convert String to Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert String of cells position into range

```
Dim closeAfcc As Integer
Dim restCases As Integer
Dim AFCCRange As String
Dim rng As Range

i = 2
closeAfcc = 0
restCases = 0
 Do
 If Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = "Closed-AFCC" Then
      closeAfcc = closeAfcc + 1
      AFCCRange = AFCCRange + "sheet1!K" & i & ","
      Else
      restCases = restCases + 1

       End If
 i = i + 1
 Loop Until Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = ""
 AFCCRange = Left(AFCCRange, Len(AFCCRange) - 1)
 Set rng = Range(AFCCRange)
```

I got `Error 1004`

my string result is
`AFCCRange= sheet1!K2,sheet1!K3,sheet1!K4,sheet1!K6,sheet1!K7,sheet1!K8,sheet1!K9,sheet1!K10,sheet1!K11,sheet1!K12`

Thanks

Comment: This code does hard-code in "sheet1" as the tab name of the sheet with a codename of `Sheet1` - is this name correct?

Comment: yes, this is the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
AFCCRange = AFCCRange + "sheet1!K" & i & ","
```

To read:

```
AFCCRange = AFCCRange & "'sheet1'!$K$" & i & ", "
```

Also change:

```
AFCCRange = Left(AFCCRange, Len(AFCCRange) - 1)
```

To read:

```
AFCCRange = Left(AFCCRange, Len(AFCCRange) - 2)
```